# jquery multiselect width in percentage

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have made jsfiddle to make it clear:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9smf/5/

I am trying to use jquery multiselect and place width as percentage (`not fixed pixel`),
but it is taking its width on document width not on it's parent's width.

Do anyone has any idea?

Comment: What's the problem ? the div is `width:49%;` and the ddl is 96% of that.

Comment: is there supposed to be a difference between the red and green one? for me it looks the same and seems rather ok

Comment: strange, I will try to make you clear, check id with "example" and it's width, and it's parent width too...

Comment: yes.. It is working perfectly. it is taking the width base on parent width.

Comment: are you sure, taking width with parent ?? check again, parent width is 49% of document and multiselect should appear on parent's width, not document's width

Comment: Yes ... it refers to parent element width

Comment: please check jsfiddle again, I tried to put some comment there,